# Find if a value is close to another value

Tags: python, python-3.x

This should be fairly straightforward in python, I just can't seem to put the right search together in google. But let's say I have two int values, `a` and `b`, that range 1 - 10 and `a=6`. I want to find out if b is either 7 or 8 (within 1 +/- value of 6). How can I do that efficiently in python?

Comment: `a-1 < b < a+1` ?

Comment: @OmarEinea I believe OP said integers, the only integer between `a-1` and `a+1` is `a`, in which case `a==b`, perhaps you meant `a-1 <= b <= a+1`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be **5** or 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in` operator:

```
>>> b in (7, 8)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Omar Einea comment to your question has a valid answer. You could wrap it into a lambda function:

```
def test_within(a,b): return a-1 <= b <= a+1

a = 6
b = 7 

test_within(a, b) # True
```

If you are only worried about integers, you could use the `in` operator, similarly to [what @zulu have pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49091188/2029132):

```
def test_within(a,b): return b in [a-1, a+1] # or [a-1, a, a+1] to catch a==b


a = 6
b = 7 

test_within(a, b) # True
```

The first solution was a little faster when testing using the `%timeit` magic on IPython (232 ns Vs. 285 ns).

Comment: These two solutions aren't the same, the second will return False where `a==b` while the first won't

Comment: @NickA, you are correct. I added a small comment explaining it.

Comment: [Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.](http://pep8.org/#programming-recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```
a=6
b=7
res = [x  for x in range(10) if abs(x-a)==1]
print(b in res)
```

Comment: He said "efficiently"

Comment: Good job using `abs`!